# Vue 3 list does not update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

We are fetching data from API like:

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted, inject } from 'vue'

let list = [];

function init() {
    axios
        .post("/some-link/here")
        .then((o) => {
            list = o.data.bla;
            console.log(list);
        })
        .catch((o) => {
            //TO DO 
        });
}

onMounted(() => {
    init();
});
</script>
```

The `console.log` shows the list properly.

But on the template, it does not update.

```
<p v-for="(val, index) in list" :key="index">
   {{ val.name }}
</p>
```

Comment: `import { ref, onMounted, inject } from 'vue'` and `const list = ref([])` and `list.value = o.data.bla;` and then re-read how to use vue3

Answer (score 0):

This works well

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

const users = ref([]);

async function fetchData() {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  return await response.json();
}

onMounted(async () => {
  users.value = await fetchData();
});
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
    {{ user.id }}  {{ user.name }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is [a playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpdkk1OwzAQha8y8iqVWmcf2kpIbDkBZmGcCXWpf2Q7qaooB2DJCbgiR2BstxViE9njed+8mcnMHr3n04isY9uogvYJIqbR74XVxruQYIaAwxqcfXajTdjDAkNwBgQjmWAPwgqrnI0Jxoghwi7nNy+vq/Ii48UqGEarknYWBkzq8CSTbFYwCwtQlQGjpwOSWJ6lTjWvEeyQko9d2x6js/4kFR7cqcfA08Vr5Xrkypm21BUsFwRCpTHYK+bG5Vnf5IQlm7r30lR7ZGa3r34Ki0/yNP4zU01nQv5s2zosGhNdEhoyl5BuANteTzBtBhd2gmUcaFuxgkH3gZdrmOtesKIAmOeSQSFYFvj5/vq8h6w0SMFCbglNim37pyBbs7qojZG+9EmrLK2I6wPV7WpzOVaW1tHhNto4qPwDHCN34b2lEw80G22QYzSbt+DO2caRKBlBRha2/AITVseA).

Answer (score 0):

you should use ref/reactive for reactive data
let list = ref([]);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).